# Footer will not adjust to page size

Tags: html, css, footer

I want my footer to adjust the page size or the size of the screen on my mobile device so that it doesn't look like a very large empty footer.

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footerwrapper">
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    height:100%;
    border-top: 1px dashed #FDF3E7;
    background-color:#250800;
    text-align:left;
}

.footerwrapper { border-bottom: 1px dotted #3B3738;padding:50px;min-height:200px; background-color:#220a03; margin: 0 auto; }
```

As shown above, I tried to overlap the wrapper with my parent footer, but it doesn't really work the way I want. I actually only want that the footer fills in the rest of the page (also on mobile devices), without flooding the footer. Anyone?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css file:

```
footer{
    min-height:200px; //you can define any height you like!
}
footer .footerwrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #3B3738;
    background-color:#220a03; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;// this width you can define your self
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the css for `footer` like bellow.

```
footer {
    border-top: 1px dashed #FDF3E7;
    background-color: #250800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7Ybrn/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, you can do this to adjust your height

```
$windowHeight = $('window').height()
$mainDivHeight = $('.yourMainDiv').height()
$footerHeight = $('footer').height()

// check if the space is larger your footer height then adjust to that height for footer
if(($windowHeight - $mainDivHeight) > $footerHeight ) {
    $('footer').height($windowHeight - $mainDivHeight)
}
```